# Appropriate systemd unit location for software not installed using a package manager

Tags: systemd, daemon

According to https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html, the default unit path is…

- /etc/systemd/system: Local configuration
- /run/systemd/system: Runtime units
- /usr/lib/systemd/system: Units of installed packages

If I am writing a script to install software to a server, not using a package manager, none of these locations seems to be technically correct.

Since this is being set up by an installer script, /usr/lib/systemd/system directory seems more right than /etc/systemd/system, even though the Linux distro's package manager is not being used. Is that right?

I thought about trying to modify the `SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH` to incude something like /opt/lib/systemd/system, but I'm pretty sure that is a bad idea.

Comment: `/etc/systemd/system` seems fine to me. It's the documented path for what you are looking for. What is your specific problem with it?

Comment: Clarifying the question.

Comment: Actually I'd recommend learning how to build packages your package manager can deal with. It's much more convenient for maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little bit confused: why didn't you use systemctl?
I suggest, that the pathes used are different in different distros, thus I would use that programm to be compatible across distros and to future modifications!

Comment: Ah. You mean using `systemctl link <path>`? I didn't know it existed until I read the docs for `systemctl` after reading your answer. I think this is the answer to my question, and I'll give it a try.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer.  Can you improve your answer to suggest how you would actually use systemctl to install a unit file?  For example, the man page does not make clear if link is a temporary solution or survives reboots.  Moreover, simply trying to link a file, if you meant `systemctl link` just results in `Failed to link unit: Invalid argument` for me.